# ¿Como realizar varias solicitudes POST a una API tratando sus datos en medio de cada una de ellas?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios

¿Como puedo realizar una serie de peticiones post para el consumo de una API? En medio de cada una de las peticiones, las respuestas deben ser tratadas para retornar solo lo que es de significancia para el próximo paso.

Ejemplo:

```
const obtenerTicket = async () => {

    const respuesta = await axios.post('url', 'username=user&password=pass', {
        headers:headers
    }).then( (res) => {

        const {headers, ...data} = res;
        const arrayUrl = headers.location.split('/');
        const secPath = arrayUrl[arrayUrl.length-1];
        return secPath;
//En este momento quiero retornar esa variable para usarla en la URL de la proxima peticion

    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })


}
```

Esta respuesta es necesaria una parte para la próxima petición post:

```
const accesoServicio = async () => {

    const path = await obtenerTicket();

    path.then( (url) => {

        axios.post(`url/${url}`, 'body', {
            headers:headers
        }).then( (res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch ( (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        } )
    } ).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    } )

}

});
```

Y así sucesivamente.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que al retornar los valores las variables que defino en el cuerpo de las próximas funciones me quedan como undefined.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Muchas gracias y espero que se entienda la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es retornar el llamado a axios (que es una promesa), así:

```
const obtenerTicket = async () => {

    return axios.post('url', 'username=user&password=pass', {
        headers:headers
    }).then( (res) => {

        const {headers, ...data} = res;
        const arrayUrl = headers.location.split('/');
        const secPath = arrayUrl[arrayUrl.length-1];
        return secPath;
//En este momento quiero retornar esa variable para usarla en la URL de la proxima peticion

    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })    
}
```

Y en esta funcion puedes quitar el then, así

```
const accesoServicio = async () => {

    const url = await obtenerTicket();

    axios.post(`url/${url}`, 'body', {
       headers:headers
    }).then( (res) => {
       console.log(res)
    }).catch ( (err) => {
       console.log(err)
    })
    

}

});
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funcionó perfecto.